# gem 'remotipart' does not show error in server rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am using this in my gemfile: `gem 'remotipart'`

defined in my form view new.html.erb

```
<%=form_for @user, remote: true, html: { multipart: true, class: 'user-form' } do |f| %>

    <div id='file_browse'>
      <%= f.file_field :image, :id => 'file_browse' %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
     </div>    
<%end%>
```

Controller method :

```
def create
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

and my create.js.erb

```
<% if remotipart_submitted? %>
  alert('submitted via remotipart')
<% else %>
  alert('error in uploading image')
<% end %>
```

its giving this error  **413:Request Entity Too Large** in server but not showing it in a page its not fetching my alert message i.e unable to catch error. Please help me out in finding way.  Don't want to give this `client_max_body_size 2M;`handle its error with rails app its fetching error from nginx request does not go through rails app

Comment: are you using ngnix web server ?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error from ngnix and not from rails.

you can fix this error by changing `client_max_body_size` attribute in Nginx configuration.

See this [article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-nginx-413-request-entity-too-large/) for more details.

Comment: No requirement is that not define `client_max_body_size` in nginx server

Comment: Your comment is not clear, BTW you have to increase upload limit of ngnix and after that you can handle rails upload errors in your code.

Comment: I mean requirement is not to do changes in ngnix server I need o handle this in my rails project code only

Comment: You can handle error in rails code if error is raised by your rails application. In this case your request is not reaching rails application, ngnix is throwing error.

Comment: yes exactly ngnix is throwing error request is not reaching to rails app. And am not getting any solution of it

Comment: I doubt if this is even possible.

Answer (score -1):

Please try like this it may help you :

In your create.js.erb

```
<%= remotipart_response do %>
  <% if remotipart_submitted? %>
     alert('submitted via remotipart')
  <% else %>
     alert('error in uploading image')
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```